# Como quito este cursor de texto en NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

soy estudiante de programacion y hasta ahora me estoy familiarizando con NetBeans y Java, creo que active esta funcion por error y no se como devolver a la normalidad el cursor de texto, antes solo aparecia una linea titilando y ahora es una caja ¡¡como la desactivo!! ...Gracias!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso es modo insertar, busca en tu teclado una tecla que diga `INS` para desactivarlo .

Comment: Si tu computadora tiene teclado numeral, remueve el bloqueo del numeral (bloqNum) y presiona la tecla del cero.

Comment: Como te indica @FranAcuna esa tecla puede decir **insert** y si no estás usando un portatil es usual encontrarla al lado izquierdo de la tecla **inicio** o **home**

Answer (score 3):

es un error que se sule cometer, seleciona en alguna parte en tu editor y únicamente das en la tecla <kbd>Insert</kbd> en tu teclado, se encuentra en la parte superior derecha con eso debe estar solucionado

Answer (score 0):

Es un error común, yo le doy a <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>SUPR</kbd> o a <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>INSERT</kbd> y de ese modo se sale del modo edición.